# Error writing a file using spark in minio s3 FileAlreadyExistsException:Can't make directory for path since it is a file

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, minio

I'm trying to write a file to a minio s3 storage installed locally using spark.
I launch spark with:

```
pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.2,io.minio:spark-select_2.11:2.1,org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.1034,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.1034,joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9 --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=+++ --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=+++ --conf "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=http://localhost:9000" --conf "spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled=false" --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

i read a csv file by hitting on pyspark:

```
df = spark.read.csv("s3a://minio/veryfirstbucket/hurricanes.csv")
```

i try writing a file by hitting on pyspark:

```
df.write.json("s3a://minio/veryfirstbucket/test_1")
```

But i get:

```
An error occurred while calling o85.json.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Can't make directory for path 's3a://minio/veryfirstbucket' since it is a file.
```

Do you know why this is happening?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, `s3a://minio/veryfirstbucket` **does** "exist", but without seeing your data, unclear why it thinks that it is a "file"

Comment: mino has some compatibility issues with hadoop 3.3.x s3a connector in single host deployments...search on the asf jira for the topic and workarounds